# How to apply default theme to ngx-mat-datetime-picker?

Tags: datetimepicker, ngxs, angular15, mat-datepicker

I'm using Angular 15, but somehow the ngx-mat-datetime-picker styling got disturbed; I'm not able to see which date has been selected while clicking on the calendar date, but functionality-wise, it's working fine as I'm getting output as per my requirements. How should I apply its default theme to the datetime picker?

Thanks in advance.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hs8SI.png)

I tried the latest version, which supports Angular 15, and also tried to change its CSS file from Node Modules.